# bash script input from pipe and wc -m

Tags: linux, bash, pipe, wc

I have this code:

```
#!/bin/bash
# ~/test.sh
if [[ -p /dev/stdin ]]; then
var="-"
else
var="$1"
fi
l=$(cat -n "$var" | wc -l)
c=$(cat -n "$var" | wc -m)
echo l=$l
echo c=$c
```

If i run:

```
$ ./test.sh file.txt
l=73
c=4909 # it is correct
```

but if

```
cat file.txt | ./test.sh
l=73
c=0    #why i have 0???
```

i don't understand why i have c=0

`cat file.txt | cat -n - | wc -c` works;  so what's the problem with my code?

what am I doing wrong?

how can i make it work properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pipe rather than open a file, the difference is that the piped-in or `stdin` is a stream (no seek back to start).

```sh
l=$(cat -n "$var" | wc -l)
```

Consumes the whole stream to count lines.

When it reaches:

```sh
c=$(cat -n "$var" | wc -m)
```

The `stdin` stream has all been consumed by the previous counting of lines. It has nothing to count left, thus returning `0`.

Fortunately `wc` can do both on the same run, and then you can read the result values like this:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

var=${1--}
if [ -p /dev/stdin ]; then
  if [ $# -ge 1 ]; then
    printf %s\\n 'Need either stdin or filename argument (not both)!' >&2
    exit 1
  fi
elif [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
  printf %s\\n 'Need stdin or a single filename argument!' >&2
  exit 1
fi
read -r l c _ < <(wc -lm -- "$var")
printf 'l=%d\nc=%d\n' "$l" "$c"
```

Answer (score 1):

The first `cat` consumes standard input until end of file; there is then no way to read the same data again for the second `cat`.

The usual solution to this is to use a temporary file; but if you just want the different counts from `wc`, run it once and extract them both from its output.

```sh
set -- $(cat -n "${@--}" | wc -l -m)
l=$1
c=$2
```

Notice also how the parameter expansion `"${@--}"` expands to either `"$@"` or `-` depending on whether the script received arguments.